# Эффективная фильтрация значений перечисления

Tags: c#, enum

Существует некое перечисление. Для примера возьмём дни недели:

```cs
public enum DaysOfWeek {
  Unknown = 0,
  Monday = 1,
  Tuesday = 2,
  Wednesday = 3,
  Thursday = 4,
  Friday = 5,
  Saturday = 6,
  Sunday = 7
}
```

Для итерации всех значений можно использовать статический метод [Enum.GetValues(Type)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8). Для некоторых сценариев необходимо отфильтровать значения перечисления, чтоб они не попадали в результирующий массив значений. На данный момент я делаю это так:

```cs
foreach(DaysOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek))) {
  if(day == default || day == DaysOfWeek.Sunday) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Очевидно, что если будет необходимо отфильтровать большое количество значений, то выражение разрастётся. Помимо этого возникает чувство, что предложенное решение является неким "костылём".
В связи с чем возникает вопрос: является ли указанный способ оптимальным решением с точки зрения производительности? Имеется ли другой способ отфильтровать не нужные или нужные значения перечисления без потери производительности?

Comment: храните ненужные значения в хешсете и фильтруйте по нему. Или храните уже нужные значения в какой то коллекции и не фильтруйте ничего.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы сделал бы так:

```
    IEnumerable<DaysOfWeek> ApplyFilter(Func<DaysOfWeek,bool> predicate)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek)).Cast<DaysOfWeek>().Where(predicate);
    }
```

Пусть снаружи кто-то передает необходимый фильтр.

Можно сделать статические функции стандартных фильтров: только выходные, только будни и т д...

Если будет очень много значений, то как сказали в комментариях, нужно использовать какую-то специализированную коллекцию, например `HashSet`.

Answer (score -1):

Предложу такой вариант.

Делаем перечисление с атрибутом [Flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8):

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64,
    All = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
}
```

Далее используем его так:

```
// Значения, которые нужно отфильтровать
var exclude = DaysOfWeek.Wednesday | DaysOfWeek.Saturday;

var result = DaysOfWeek.All ^ exclude;
// var result = DaysOfWeek.All & ~exclude; // тот же результат

Console.WriteLine(result);

foreach (Enum day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek)))
{
    if (result.HasFlag(day))
        Console.Write(day + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Вывод в консоль `result` - все значения сразу:

> Monday, Tuesday, Thursday, Friday, Sunday

Вывод цикла в консоль - присутствует `Unknown`:

> Unknown Monday Tuesday Thursday Friday Sunday

---

Если значение `All` в перечислении категорически не нужно, можно убрать его и вместо него в коде использовать:

```
DaysOfWeek all = 0;
foreach (DaysOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek)))
    all |= day;

var result = all ^ exclude;
```

---

Метод `HasFlag` известен своей медлительностю. Поэтому, если нужна производительность, заменим его битовыми операциями:

```
foreach (DaysOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek)))
{
    if ((result & day) == day)
        Console.Write(day + " ");
}
```

---

Уже написав ответ, я понял, что всё изящество строки `var result = all ^ exclude;` и простота задания фильтра через `|` (ради чего я затеял ответ) несколько теряется необходимостью последующего цикла.

Answer (score -1):

Итак, предложу свой вариант:

Так как Вы упомянули, что перечисления могут быть достаточно большими, а также Вам критична производительность, то от постоянного использования рефлексии в лице `Enum.GetValues` стоит отказаться!

Предлагаю создать вспомогательный тип для обработки перечислений желаемым Вами способом. Приступим!

Для начала создадим такой вот атрибут:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class EnumBlacklistAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool Blacklisted { get; }

    public EnumBlacklistAttribute() : this(true) { }
    public EnumBlacklistAttribute(bool Blacklisted) => this.Blacklisted = Blacklisted;
}
```

Теперь Ваше перечисление можно записать так:

```
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    [EnumBlacklist]
    Unknown = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
    [EnumBlacklist]
    Sunday = 7
}
```

То есть *нежелательные* значения помечены созданным нами атрибутом

Теперь определим вспомогательный класс (надеюсь, из комментариев ясна основная суть действа):

```
public static class EnumEnumerator<TEnum> where TEnum : Enum
{
    // Здесь будут храниться все значения enum'a
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<TEnum> Values;
    // Здесь будут храниться все нежелательные значения enum'a
    private static readonly HashSet<TEnum> Blacklist;
    // А здесь создадим связку имя/соотвествующий элемент перечисления
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, TEnum> NamedValues;

    static EnumEnumerator()
    {
        // Инициализируем контейнеры
        List<TEnum> valuesList = new List<TEnum>();
        NamedValues = new Dictionary<string, TEnum>();
        Blacklist = new HashSet<TEnum>();

        // Пройдемся по каждому статическому полю типа перечисления 
        foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(TEnum).GetFields().Where(x => x.IsStatic))
        {
            TEnum val = (TEnum)field.GetValue(null);
            valuesList.Add(val);
            if (field.GetCustomAttribute<EnumBlacklistAttribute>()?.Blacklisted ?? false)
                Blacklist.Add(val);
            NamedValues[field.Name.ToLower()] = val;
        }
        Values = valuesList.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetValues() => Values;

    // Получение значения по имени
    public static bool TryGetValue(string Name, out TEnum Value) => NamedValues.TryGetValue(Name.ToLower(), out Value);

    // Проверка, находится ли элемент в "черном списке"
    public static bool Blacklisted(TEnum Value) => Blacklist.Contains(Value);
    // Проверка, не находится ли элемент в "черном списке"
    public static bool Whitelisted(TEnum Value) => !Blacklist.Contains(Value);

    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> WhereBlacklisted(IEnumerable<TEnum> Enumerable) => Enumerable.Where(Blacklisted);
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> WhereWhitelisted(IEnumerable<TEnum> Enumerable) => Enumerable.Where(Whitelisted);
}
```

Увы, `generic`-класс не может содержать в себе методов-расширений, так что определим вспомогательный класс для вспомогательного класса :D

```
public static class EnumEnumerator
{
    public static bool Whitelisted<T>(this T Value) where T : Enum => EnumEnumerator<T>.Whitelisted(Value);
    public static bool Blacklisted<T>(this T Value) where T : Enum => EnumEnumerator<T>.Blacklisted(Value);

    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereBlacklisted<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Enumerable) where T : Enum => EnumEnumerator<T>.WhereBlacklisted(Enumerable);
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereWhitelisted<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Enumerable) where T : Enum => EnumEnumerator<T>.WhereWhitelisted(Enumerable);
}
```

---

Ну вот и все!
Теперь мы с чистой совестью можем писать так:

```
foreach (var day in EnumEnumerator<DaysOfWeek>.GetValues().WhereWhitelisted())
    Console.WriteLine("Whitelisted: {0}", day);

Console.WriteLine();

foreach (var day in EnumEnumerator<DaysOfWeek>.GetValues().WhereBlacklisted())
    Console.WriteLine("Blacklisted: {0}", day);
```

Вывод:

> Whitelisted: Monday
>   Whitelisted: Tuesday
>   Whitelisted: Wednesday
>   Whitelisted: Thursday
>   Whitelisted: Friday
>   Whitelisted: Saturday
>
> Blacklisted: Unknown
>   Blacklisted: Sunday

---

Наш метод использует медленную рефлексию только один раз! После чего, почерпнув все необходимые данные, использует закэшированные значения. Так что Вы спокойно и быстро можете определить, является ли значение перечисления *нежелательным* и наоборот, а также я добавил возможность получения элемента перечисления по его имени)

Надеюсь, мое решение было Вам полезным!